# C++ how to reset a counter to 0 when a function is called?

Tags: c++, loops, count

I have a question regarding the reset of a counter back to 0. Below is my function

```
std::string passorFail(double performanceScore, int threshHold)
{

  if (performanceScore > threshHold)
  {
    pass++; //if the judge socres a pass, 1 is added to the counter
    return "pass";
  }
  else
  {
    return "fail";
    
  }
}
```

An int variable called '''int pass = 0;''' is declared globally in the scope as it is required by another function. It's called in a way similar to this (PS it has to be global)

```
somefunction(pass);
```

Right now this is how the counter behaves. In total the function passorFail is called 4 times as it loops through a vector, and each time it loops through it increments as it should. So an output is something like this.

```
count after first pass: 3
count after first pass: 5//increases by 2
count after first pass: 8//increases by 3
count after first pass: 12//increases by 4
```

What I want to do is display how much the count increments by in each iteration, so something more like this rather than what's displayed above.

```
count of first pass: 3
count of first pass: 2
count of first pass: 3
count of first pass: 4
```

I tried setting pass to 0 after I return "pass" in the if statement like the below code, however it still displays the total number of passes rather than how much it increases by in each iteration.

```
if (performanceScore > threshHold)
  {
    pass++; 
    return "pass";
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated :) thankyou

Comment: This question would be improved if it had a [mre] instead of a code snippet that does work and merely a textual description of your interpretation of the code that does not. (That is, you tried something -- setting pass to 0 -- and it did not work as you expected. That means there is something in the code you do not understand. Why should we trust your understanding of the code?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the code that prints the count, but what you want is a separate variable that keeps track of the value of `pass` the last time it was printed.  So you want something like this:

```
printf("count of first pass: %d\n", pass - lastpass);
lastpass = pass;
```

Comment: so something like this  ```int lastPass = pass; int printPass = pass-lastPass; ```

Comment: @davylang You'll want to define `lastPass` globally and initialize it to 0.  Then you modify the value *after* printing the difference.

Comment: Okay thankyou that does seem to work. How can i use that value but? declaring something like ```int x = pass - lastpass``` doesnt work

Comment: all good man igore that last comment. I mucked around and finally got the answer i need, thankyou!!